Triple Integration of a Volleyball Serve
So I am a student that is working on a project that the end goal is to calculate the total volume of a 3D form created from quadratic equations that I already know and plotted in a Desmos 3D graphing calculator. (I know this may not be the best 3D graphing calculator but I wanted to stay consistent with my graphing software as I have used Desmos for 2D breakdown graphs for easy visualisation)
Essentially, the way I am visualising the 3D form is a square based pyramid that the peak has been pulled down to the side. Except the bottom edges have inverted to be on top of the top edges (sorry it's hard to explain).Sketch of what I believe the 3D form is (the lines are just to visualise the surface of the 3D form),
Side view of volleyball serve, I asked various Math teachers at my school about this 3D form and they all couldn't guide me to a direction that they are confident in. One of my teachers suggested to ask here in Math stack exchange.
I can visualise what the faces of this complex 3D form. However, I cannot come up with a mathematical equation for the faces that are twisting.
3D view of volleyball serve (The blue faces that are there I have already found out, but the faces that are missing is what I am struggling with.) Top view of volleyball serve
I will need an equation to have the upper bound of the Z integral in rectangular coordinates. Ultimately this is a complex 3D form so I will have to approach the calculation of the volume by cutting the form into multiple pieces to be able to easily triple integrate.
Desmos 3D Graph
To summarise, my question is: How can I get a mathematical equation to the twisting face of the morphed square based pyramid that represents a volleyball serve? I will need this to have an upper limit of my Z integral when integrating.

It looks like you’re taking the graph of a parabola in the $xz$-plane and letting the height be independent of $y$ (in a certain fixed closed interval). The 3D figure will just be a portion of a cylinder (parallel to the $y$-axis). Is this a correct interpretation of your figures? BTW, what’s a plausible physical interpretation of this volume?

So initially I had my parabolas on the zy-plane and the constraint was a a line created on the xy-plane (because Desmos 3D creates sheets if the z-axis is involved in the function, so that is why I had to constrain that sheet to a line in the xy-plane). A cylinder would not work I believe for this case as it would be much easier to have it in rectangular coordinates? (since I believe cylindrical coordinates will have a rounded edge from the center) I can edit my original question to include an image of what I am imagining and what I believe it to be.

I didn't say a circular cylinder. Any surface consisting of a family of parallel lines (following the contour of an arbitrary curve) is called a cylinder. That is what you are drawing in your pictures. I still am curious what the physical interpretation of this volume integral is. It sounds more like a standard math problem with the "volleyball serve" thrown in to make it sound more interesting.

@user170231 Thank you, this is very similar to what I have, however I can see where it was misleading or lacking information (I deeply apologize), but I have now updated the post to include a top down view. What you've got is almost what I'm looking for, but between the end of the blue region and the orange region ends should be a square/rectangle because that is the confines of the volleyball court. Again, I apologize for the lack of detail.

I see, so more like this (ignoring the sloppy code; click and drag on the plot to rotate. NB I've moved the net to $y=0$). One thing you can do is parameterize the arcs where each cylinder meets its respective planar bounds, then parameterize the surface joining them. This is done with$$\vec s(y,t)=(1-t)\vec r_R(y)+t\vec r_G(y)$$where $0\le t\le1$ (related). From there, it's a question of converting from parametric to Cartesian coordinates.

Thank you so much @user170231! I will have to go over this working out with my teachers to properly understand. Although this might just be a visual limitation of my screen, but it appears that the gold/yellow face is sort of concave. I am not sure if that is due to the formula you are using or if that your visualization is more accurate than what I thought it would look like. Again, I really appreciate your help, but as of now I am still unsure if my question is answered as I have to go through it with my teachers to properly understand this. However, this looks very promising.

I've updated the code, the surface parametrization should be correct now. (I neglected to mention $\vec r_R$ and $\vec r_G$ refer to the parametric equations for the $R$ed and $G$reen arcs)
